# Rails view not showing content

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been staring at this code way too long and up to 3 days ago, the code worked fine, so I'm hoping some fresh eyes will help.

My view is supposed to render network hosts for a location.  Then it splits the hosts in to two tabs: hosts w/ a security percentage less than 99%, and hosts that have a security percentage of 99% or higher.  My view is only rendering the hosts that have a security percentage of 99% or higher though.

**network_hosts_controller.rb**

```html
class V1::NetworkHostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_location
  before_action :set_network_host, only: [:show]

  def index
    @network_hosts = NetworkHost.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_location
    @location = Location.find_by!(identifier: params[:location_id])
  end

  def set_network_host
    @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**models/network_host.rb**

```html
class NetworkHost < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :network_host_tests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parent_tests, through: :network_host_tests

  validates_presence_of :location, :mac_address, :ip_address
  validates_uniqueness_of :mac_address

  delegate :security_percentage, to: :last_test, allow_nil: true

  def name
    if self.hostname.blank?
      self.ip_address
    else
      "#{self.ip_address} (#{self.hostname})"
    end
  end

  def last_test
    network_host_tests.last
  end

  def test_before_last_test
    network_host_tests.offset(1).last
  end
end
```

**views/network_hosts/_index.html.erb**

```html
<section id="network-hosts" class="list-outer">
  <header class="section-header hosts-header clearfix">
    <h3>Network Hosts by Risk</h3>
  </header>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="$('#hosts-list-issues').show();$('#hosts-list-scanned').hide();" >Hosts at Risk</a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="$('#hosts-list-issues').hide();$('#hosts-list-scanned').show();">Scanned Hosts</a></li>
  </ul>

  <% network_hosts = network_hosts.sort_by{|e| e.security_percentage} %>
  <div id="hosts-list-issues" class="hosts dl-menuwrapper">
    <ul class="dl-menu">
      <% network_hosts.each do |network_host| %>
        <% if network_host.security_percentage < 99 %>
          <% next unless last_test = network_host.last_test %>
          <li class="clearfix">
            <a href="#" class="last-test-notif <%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
              <div class="tooltip-content" data-status="<%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
                <p class="last-test-label">Last Test: </p>
                <% if last_test %>
                  <span class="last-test-date"><%= last_test.date.to_s(:humanized_ago) %></span>
                <% else %>
                  -
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="host-graph-wrapper">
                <div class="host-chart" data-percent="<%= network_host.security_percentage %>">
                  <span class="host-percent"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="host-data">
              <p><span class="host-address"><%= network_host.name %></span></p>
              <p><span class="num-issues">
                <% if last_test.results.count > 0 %>
                  <%= last_test.results.count %></span> Issues Detected: <span class="severity"><%= last_test.results.count %> Major</span>, <span class="severity"><%= last_test.results.count %> Minor
                <% else %>
                  No Issues Detected
                <% end %>
              </span></p>
            </div>
          </a>

            <ul class="dl-submenu">
              <li class="overview">
                <a href="#" class="last-test-notif <%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
                  <div class="tooltip-content" data-status="<%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
                    <p class="last-test-label">Last Test: </p>
                    <% if last_test %>
                      <span class="last-test-date"><%= last_test.date.to_s(:humanized_ago) %></span>
                    <% else %>
                      -
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="host-graph-wrapper">
                  <div class="host-chart" data-percent="<%= network_host.security_percentage %>">
                    <span class="host-percent"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="host-data">
                  <p><span class="host-address"><%= network_host.name %></span></p>
                  <p>
                    <span class="host-mac-address">
                      <a href="http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=<%= network_host.mac_address %>" target="_blank" onclick="return confirm('You are about to be redirect to an external website.')"><%= network_host.mac_address %></a>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <p><span class="num-issues">
                    <% if last_test.results.count > 0 %>
                      <%= last_test.results.count %></span> Issues Detected: <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "major").count %> Major</span>, <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "minor").count %> Minor
                    <% else %>
                      No Issues Detected
                    <% end %>
                  </span></p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <% last_test.results.each do |result| %>
                <% issue = result.issue %>
                <li class="port-list">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="status-dot <%= issue.minor? ? 'yellow' : 'red' %>"></span>
                    <span class="port-list-port"><%= issue.name %></span>
                  </a>

                  <ul class="dl-submenu description">
                    <li class="content">
                      <h5><%= issue.name %></h5>
                      <h6>Description</h6>
                      <p><%= issue.description || "-" %></p>
                      <h6>Problem</h6>
                      <p><%= issue.problem || "-" %></p>
                      <h6>The Fix</h6>
                      <p><%= issue.solution || "-" %></p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- End issue details -->
                </li>
                <!-- End issue content -->
              <% end %>
              <!-- End results -->
            </ul>
            <!-- End submenu -->
          </li>
          <!-- End clearfix -->
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <!-- End network_hosts -->
    </ul>
    <!-- End ul -->
  </div>
  <!-- End hosts -->

  <div id="hosts-list-scanned" class="hosts dl-menuwrapper" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="dl-menu">
      <% network_hosts.each do |network_host| %>
      <% if network_host.security_percentage >= 99 %>
        <% next unless last_test = network_host.last_test %>

        <li class="clearfix">

          <a href="#" class="last-test-notif <%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
            <div class="tooltip-content" data-status="<%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
              <p class="last-test-label">Last Test: </p>
              <% if last_test %>
                <span class="last-test-date"><%= last_test.date.to_s(:humanized_ago) %></span>
              <% else %>
                -
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href="#">
            <div class="host-graph-wrapper">
              <div class="host-chart" data-percent="<%= network_host.security_percentage %>">
                <span class="host-percent"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="host-data">
              <p><span class="host-address"><%= network_host.name %></span></p>
              <p><span class="num-issues">
                <% if last_test.results.count > 0 %>
                  <%= last_test.results.count %></span> Issues Detected: <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "major").count %> Major</span>, <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "minor").count %> Minor
                <% else %>
                  No Issues Detected
                <% end %>
              </span></p>
            </div>
          </a>

          <ul class="dl-submenu">
            <li class="overview">
              <a href="#" class="last-test-notif <%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
                <div class="tooltip-content" data-status="<%= last_test.security_percentage_movement_since_last_test %>">
                  <p class="last-test-label">Last Test: </p>
                  <% if last_test %>
                    <span class="last-test-date"><%= last_test.date.to_s(:humanized_ago) %></span>
                  <% else %>
                    -
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div class="host-graph-wrapper">
                <div class="host-chart" data-percent="<%= network_host.security_percentage %>">
                  <span class="host-percent"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="host-data">
                <p><span class="host-address"><%= network_host.name %></span></p>
                <p>
                  <span class="host-mac-address">
                    <a href="http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=<%= network_host.mac_address %>" target="_blank" onclick="return confirm('You are about to be redirect to an external website.')"><%= network_host.mac_address %></a>
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p><span class="num-issues">
                  <% if last_test.results.count > 0 %>
                    <%= last_test.results.count %></span> Issues Detected: <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "major").count %> Major</span>, <span class="severity"><%= last_test.issues.where(:severity => "minor").count %> Minor
                  <% else %>
                    No Issues Detected
                  <% end %>
                </span></p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <% last_test.results.each do |result| %>
              <% issue = result.issue %>

              <li class="port-list">
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="status-dot <%= issue.minor? ? 'yellow' : 'red' %>"></span>
                  <span class="port-list-port"><%= issue.name %></span>
                </a>

                <ul class="dl-submenu description">
                  <li class="content">
                    <h5><%= issue.name %></h5>
                    <h6>Description</h6>
                    <p><%= issue.description || "-" %></p>
                    <h6>Problem</h6>
                    <p><%= issue.problem || "-" %></p>
                    <h6>The Fix</h6>
                    <p><%= issue.solution || "-" %></p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- End issue details -->

              </li>
              <!-- End issue content -->

            <% end %>
            <!-- End results -->

          </ul>
          <!-- End submenu -->

        </li>
        <!-- End clearfix -->
       <% end %>

      <% end %>
      <!-- End network_hosts -->

    </ul>
    <!-- End ul -->

  </div>
  <!-- End hosts -->
</section>
```

The area that should render the hosts with less than 99% security percentage is the `host-list-issues` div id, specifically the `host-data` div class, but it's not now:

[image: host-list-issues div with no content]

What's really throwing me off is that under a different login with different hosts, it does actually render:

[image: host-list-issues div with content]

I've run the code through Rails console to make sure that it's actually returning content as well:

```html
network_hosts = NetworkHost.all
  
network_hosts = network_hosts.sort_by{ |e| e.security_percentage }
  network_hosts.each do |network_host|
    if network_host.security_percentage < 99
      next unless last_test = network_host.last_test
    end
  end
end
```

Which does return objects (snippet):

```html
 #<NetworkHost id: 32, location_id: 8, mac_address: "84:38:35:AA:4D:3D", ip_address: "192.168.1.100", hostname: "A Phone", created_at: "2015-03-05 18:00:18", updated_at: "2015-06-06 14:47:04", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>,
 #<NetworkHost id: 56, location_id: 8, mac_address: "28:0D:FC:E3:5C:43", ip_address: "192.168.1.129", hostname: nil, created_at: "2015-05-21 16:03:19", updated_at: "2015-05-21 16:03:19", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>,
 #<NetworkHost id: 52, location_id: 10, mac_address: "64:76:BA:9D:11:87", ip_address: "10.10.10.102", hostname: "Razor", created_at: "2015-04-09 15:02:41", updated_at: "2015-06-07 14:55:45", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>,
 #<NetworkHost id: 41, location_id: 8, mac_address: "54:9F:13:2A:28:16", ip_address: "192.168.1.132", hostname: "Another Phone", created_at: "2015-03-05 18:00:18", updated_at: "2015-06-05 15:29:33", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>,
 #<NetworkHost id: 44, location_id: 8, mac_address: "18:20:32:C1:32:D8", ip_address: "192.168.1.138", hostname: "Thermostat", created_at: "2015-03-05 20:00:27", updated_at: "2015-06-20 15:02:55", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>,
 #<NetworkHost id: 58, location_id: 3, mac_address: "B8:27:EB:C1:43:42", ip_address: "10.10.10.133", hostname: nil, created_at: "2015-06-02 00:12:19", updated_at: "2015-06-02 00:12:19", deleted_at: nil, vendor: nil>
```

So, between having the hosts show up for some locations and not others, and results showing when I pull directly from Rails Console, I'm stumped.  Help!

Comment: I would start by a) splitting your code up into some partials so your head doesn't explode every time you look at it b) stick some logging in.

Comment: @MaxWilliams where would be the best place to stick some logging in?  Are you just talking about Logger.debug ?

Comment: this looks a bit suspicious - (in the 99 or less section) `<% next unless last_test = network_host.last_test %>` - i don't know what this is supposed to be doing but if it's not correct it's just going to skip through the entire list and not do anything.

Comment: all over the place. yep.  :)

Comment: further to my comment about the last_test stuff - have you perhaps done the classic programmer error of `=` vs `==`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I've actually tried taking out the `<% next unless last_test = network_host.last_test %>` line, but still doesn't change anything.

Comment: One thing which looks odd is that you define `@network_hosts` (instance var) in the controller and then your page refers to `network_hosts` (no @ so either a method or a local var)

Comment: You should probably be doing this in the controller or model `network_hosts = network_hosts.sort_by{|e| e.security_percentage}`

Comment: @AntarrByrd I planned on moving some of the functionality to the controller once I get it working in the view.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I commented `@network_hosts = NetworkHost.All` in the controller, so the view should take precedence.  Still same result... no hosts ;(

Comment: have you checked if the security percentage is an integer so it can do a comparison? Because now it might be the case that the first `if` fails so it only renders out what's after `else`

Comment: @Kkulikovskis this is the line that I used in the migration to create the table `t.integer :security_percentage`

Comment: Still, try putting `.to_i`. In my experience usually the problem is with the `if` statement, because it seems to be rendering only the `else` part

Comment: This question has a lot of code. Try creating a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. You could even end up debugging the issue that way.

Comment: @eirikir ok, will do